# How do I configure NGINX to pass authorisation header on rewrite

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have this NGINX config. We are using a rewrite to pass the /api to a routing PHP file.
The authorisation header is not reaching PHP, what do I need to change?

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://www.example.com";
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS";
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization";


location ~ \.php$ {
    root    /webdir/app/phpapi/;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

location /api/v1 {
    rewrite /api/v1/(.*) /code/v2/routing/index.php?params=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: A quick look on ChatGPT suggests adding `fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;` I haven't tested it, so not 100% sure, but might be worth a paste into ChatGPT and test its suggestion.